# Force the calculation of a cell by JavaScript API

Tags: ms-office, office-js

I try to run a sample from [this page](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/range) in a workbook:

```
Excel.run(function (ctx) { 
    var sheetName = "Sheet1";
    var rangeAddress = "F5:G7";
    var numberFormat = [[null, "d-mmm"], [null, "d-mmm"], [null, null]]
    var values = [["Today", 42147], ["Tomorrow", "5/24"], ["Difference in days", null]];
    var formulas = [[null,null], [null,null], [null,"=G6-G5"]];
    var range = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem(sheetName).getRange(rangeAddress);
    range.numberFormat = numberFormat;
    range.values = values;
    range.formulas= formulas;
    range.load('text');
    return ctx.sync().then(function() {
        console.log(range.text);
    });
}).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error: " + error);
        if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
            console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
        }
});
```

When the calculation mode is `automatic`, the result of `G7` is `367`. By contrast, when the calculation mode is `manual`, the result of `G7` is `0`; that means the formula `=G6-G5` is not re-evaluated.

Does anyone know if there is a way to force the calculation of `G7` by JavaScript API, under `manual` mode?

One way we could image would be to change the calculation mode (to `automatic`), however, [calculationMode](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/application) is read-only here.

Another way would be to run the method [calculate(calculationType: string)](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/application), but it recalculates all currently open workbooks in Excel, which is quite costly, and may not be what we want to do.

I feel it would be quite restricting if such a fundamental operation is not possible regardless of workarounds...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment the option way to manually trigger calculation is to use the calculate() method against the entire workbook. It shouldn't trigger this across workbooks however, only the workbook held by this application instance. The application object only references the single Excel instance running the add-in.

Comment: Is enabling calculation on cell level on the roadmap?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of that specific feature. I would absolutely recommend adding it to [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).